# Are const references to members safe

Tags: c++, reference, member, getter, invalidation

If I use a const reference to another member,
is it possible that this reference gets invalidated?

```
class Class {
public:
    const int &x{y};
private:
    int y;
};
```

For example when I use instances of this class in a vector
which increases its capacity after a `push_back`.
According to the standard all iterators and references are invalidated if
a vector has to increase its capacity. Is the reference still valid after that?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could push that into a vector and have `x` point where you think it does.

Comment: Shouldn't a push back be fine for every newly inserted `Class` instance? The data would get copied into the vector with x pointing to the new y location.

Comment: If you took the reference before `push_back()`, it won't point to that element inside of the vector. `push_back()` takes a copy.

Comment: It's actually an issue about the value being referenced not the reference itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is currently not safe, as when you copy an instance of `Class`, `x` will reference the `y` of the copied object, not its own `y`. You can see this by running the following code:

```
int main()
{
    Class a{};
    std::vector<Class> vec;
    vec.push_back(a);

    //these lines print the same address
    std::cout << &(a.x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << &(vec[0].x) << std::endl;
}
```

You can fix this by writing your own copy constructor and assignment functions to correctly initialize `x`:

```
Class (const Class& rhs) : x{y}, y{rhs.y} {}
```

This is safe, because`x` and `y` will only be destroyed along with your object. Invalidation of references for `std::vector` means references to the vector elements:

```
Class c;
std::vector<Class> vec;
vec.push_back(c);

Class& cr = vec[0];
//other operations on vec
std::cout << c.x; //fine, that reference is internal to the class
std::cout << cr.x; //cr could have been invalidated
```

Comment: Does it still work if I overwrite the copy ctor and but the vector has to grow after a push back?  Are the references then still valid?

Comment: Yes, that's what the final paragraph and snippet address.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a reference to another member from the same instance, you need to override copy constructor to initialize it. Default copy constructor will copy the reference to 'y' from the old instance which might be invalidated.

Why do you need a reference to a member is another question.

P.S. also you need to override an assignment operator for the same reason.

Comment: I thought about it as an alternative to the common getter.